# Regarding Android SQLite database structure for managing music playlists

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm new to Android and this is my first time working with `SQLite`. I'm making a music player and I'm about to add the ability to create and manage playlists.

The playlists will be stored in an SQLite database. I have two approaches in mind for this. The first one is to create a different table for each new playlist. The other approach is to use a single table for all playlists and have a "TAG" column that will contain the name of the playlist that each song belongs to. Songs of each playlist will be fetched using the tags.

Which approach, according to your experience, is a better one in terms of performance, and other important factors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that The more accurate way is to use One playList Table with the TAG or Category Column, if you go with a new table for every playlist this is going to overload your database

so a Table like this

> id | playlist name | playlist songs | TAG

EDIT

with every table added there is a Meta Data added with it from sqlite so in other words more that a single table, and you cannot assume that all Android devices have enough space available that's depending on smartphone users, secondly the amount of time to create a new database is strictly bigger that simply add a new row to the existing table, so you can favorite the first approach based on space and the query speed.

Comment: Could you clarify how  the database could be overloaded? In terms of storage capacity, I think it is safe to presume that all current Android devices have enough to store some playlist tables.

Comment: Edited with clarification

Comment: Thank you. Further discussion on this can be found here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11475338/maximum-of-tables-a-sqlite-database-file-supports)

Comment: For future visitors, I'd like to add that performance wise, having separate tables for different playlists is a better option because, in the single table approach, every time a playlist has to be accessed, there will be a WHERE clause (I don't know if I'm saying it right) that looks for songs with a specific tag. This searching can have a significant performance hit when the user has several playlists with lots of songs.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam wich approach your going to follow at the end ?

Comment: I think having a single table for similar data (i.e. song information) seems better. But I am going for different tables for different playlists because manual sorting of songs in individual playlists will be a problem if all songs of all playlists are in a single table. Also, in my experience, database operations, especially searching, take a lot of time. I know this from working with MediaStore. So after all,I'm going for multiple tables.

Comment: The single table approach will be considered if having multiple tables is too costly.