# How to create a SQLite3 database of variable name safely

Tags: python, sqlite

this is the code I would like to have, where I do not have to exactly specify the `howtodothis` variable during database creation. I want it to be dynamic instead.

```
class DbHandler():
    def __init__(self, howtodothis):
        self.database = sqlite3.connect('api_data.db')
        self.cursor = self.database.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ? (test)",(howtodothis,))

    def insert(self):
        self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ? VALUES (?)",(howtodothis,))
```

I now have this, but I wonder if it is safe

```
class DbHandler():
    def __init__(self, thisworks):
        self.database = sqlite3.connect('api_data.db')
        self.cursor = self.database.cursor()
        self.cursor.execute(f"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {thisworks} (test)")

    def insert(self):
        self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {thisworks} VALUES (?)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `thisworks` is supplied by the user, there is a risk of being random SQL injections or characters that are not legal as SQLite identifiers in there.

Generally in relational design, adding tables or columns for specific user input is a bit frowned up. Usually a better design is to use a single table, and just have a column that holds the variable `thisworks`. Because in the end, `select test from {thisworks}` is about the same as
`select test from userdata where label = ?, param = {thisworks}`, but way safer regarding injections and there's no risk of your database blowing up due to containing a bazillion tables. That being said, SQLite specifically [supports 2 billion tables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11475752/571215) in one file, so you might get away with it.

If you do it, make sure to filter the supplied variable, best with a whitelist like only allowing a-z.